# Get the calling object from superclass

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, object-oriented-analysis

I've built a "model" superclass for a MVC framework. In most methods i do need only the class name so i've used get_called_class() but for save and edit methods i need to pass the object with values.

In my design, when you create a model object and you save or edit you have to do:

`$object->save($object);`  or `$object->update($object, $id).`

I really don't like this, because looks as a bad design. I would like just to say:

```
$object->save(); and $object->update($id);
```

Since you are effectively saving the current object.

Models classes extends a Model parent that defines their behaviour and create the DB connection for them.

The methods of superclass that i would like to make does not take as an argument $object but rather i would like to say "get the calling object".

```
public function save($object) {

       return self::$db->save($object);
    }

    public function update($object,$id) {
        return self::$db->update($object, $id);
    }
```

I know that this can be easily doable the in the object model with

```
public function save () {
parent::save($this);
}
```

But i would like not to have to reimplement this behaviour for every single model!

Thank you in advance.
*The use of any existing ORM library isn't discussed here, since i want to provide a querybuilder and simple ORM that is PDO based as default. Because i do not want to have any 3rd party dependency as default*

Comment: Why not to use ORM libraries? There are plenty of them with ActiveRecord or DataMapper implementations. http://propelorm.org/ http://www.doctrine-project.org/ to name a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your base model as abstract class and inherit default behavior to child model classes.

```
abstract class Model
{
    public function save() {
      return self::$db->save($this);
    }

    public function update($id) {
        return self::$db->update($this, $id);
    }
}

class UserModel extends Model;

$myModel = new UserModel();
$myModel->save();
```

Comment: Ty i'll give a try and if it fits the reply is yours ;)

Comment: I'm sorry for confusion with an "implements" keyword. It suites for interfaces only, classes are "extends", of course.

Comment: Code working so it's ok, i already edited you mistake thanks!